# Android how to clear focus of edit text on closing keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to do two diffrent animate on gaining focus and on keyboard go down. I am trying to detect focus with this

```
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) animateUp();
            else animateDown();
        }
    });
```

The problem is when keyboard is closed edit text is still being focused and it cant animate the second one. How can I clear the focus after keyboard closed ?

Answer (score -1):

use

```
  setCursorVisible(boolean)
```

or use xml property for edittext

```
android:cursorVisible
```

to remove focus when keyboard is hidden

or use imeOptions

```
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
```